# Javascript multiple then blocks vs all data in one then block

Tags: javascript

I just had a question I couldnt find online about javascript `.then` blocks. I am using reactquery mutations that contains .then promises (not really important for this question). WHats the difference between putting all code into one .then block compared to having `.then().then().then()`? For example:

what is the standard javascript way of doing this?

```
func.then(func1).then(func2).then(func3)
```

vs.

```
func.then(() => {func1();func2();func3();})
```

Comment: You normally use multiple `.then()` blocks when each one processes the result of the previous one.

Comment: And each one is asynchronous.

Comment: There *has* to be a good original to point to for this.

Comment: The "each one is asynchronous" is an important part. I often see people doing `.then(fn1).then(fn2)` where `fn1` is *not* asynchronous - which is not the right way to do things.

Comment: `.then promises (not really important for this question)`  Ironically it is.  If there were not promises, then they would be no point in doing it, unless you wanted chained function evaluation, or curing.  But then that would be for a different reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code, I'm assuming:

1. `func` is a promise (not a function)
2. `func1` through `func3` are functions

The fundamental difference is that in your first example, the fulfillment value from `func` is passed to `func1`, and then the resulting promise's fulfillment value is passed to `func2`, and then the resulting promise's fulfillment value is passed to `func3`. Each step waits for the previous step to complete (assuming they return promises [or, technically, if they're synchronous functions]). If any of those promises is rejected rather than being fulfilled, subsequent functions will not be called.

But in your second example, the fulfillment values are never used, each function gets no arguments, and nothing waits for previous operations to complete (if they're asynchronous, which would be why you'd be using promises with them).

`func.then(func1).then(func2).then(func3)` may be clearer if we expand it a bit:

```
func.then(result0 => func1(result0))
    .then(result1 => func2(result1))
    .then(result2 => func3(result2));
```

That does the same thing as `func.then(func1).then(func2).then(func3)` (aside from creating some temporary wrapper functions).

Let's see the distinction with an example.

This uses `func.then(func1).then(func2).then(func3)`:

```js
const delay = (ms, value) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));

const rnd = () => Math.random() * 1000;

const func = delay(rnd(), "func result");

const func1 = async arg => {
    console.log(`func1 called with ${JSON.stringify(arg)}`);
    const result = await delay(rnd(), "func1 result");
    console.log(`func1 returning ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    return result;
};
const func2 = async arg => {
    console.log(`func2 called with ${JSON.stringify(arg)}`);
    const result = await delay(rnd(), "func2 result");
    console.log(`func2 returning ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    return result;
};
const func3 = async arg => {
    console.log(`func3 called with ${JSON.stringify(arg)}`);
    const result = await delay(rnd(), "func3 result");
    console.log(`func3 returning ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    return result;
};

func.then(func1).then(func2).then(func3);
```

Notice how each waited for the previous to complete, and they saw the previous results.

Here's `func.then(() => {func1();func2();func3();})`:

```js
const delay = (ms, value) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, value));

const rnd = () => Math.random() * 1000;

const func = delay(rnd(), "func result");

const func1 = async arg => {
    console.log(`func1 called with ${JSON.stringify(arg)}`);
    const result = await delay(rnd(), "func1 result");
    console.log(`func1 returning ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    return result;
};
const func2 = async arg => {
    console.log(`func2 called with ${JSON.stringify(arg)}`);
    const result = await delay(rnd(), "func2 result");
    console.log(`func2 returning ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    return result;
};
const func3 = async arg => {
    console.log(`func3 called with ${JSON.stringify(arg)}`);
    const result = await delay(rnd(), "func3 result");
    console.log(`func3 returning ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    return result;
};

func.then(() => {func1();func2();func3();})
```

Notice how they don't see previous results, and they overlap their work, there's no coordination between them.

---

In both cases, it's important that you either handle promise rejection in your code, or return the final promise in the chain (the result of the last `then`) to code that will handle rejection. Otherwise, you'll get an unhandled rejection, which in some environments (like Node.js) will get your process terminated.

Answer (score 2):

The first style is used when `func1` and `func2` are asynchronous, and the result of each is used as the argument to the next one. A common example is found in many uses of `fetch()`:

```
fetch(params)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => db.query(...))
    .then((res, err) => { do something with query results })
```

The second style can be used if these are all ordinary functions.

Comment: Don't forget the `ok` check in that first `then`! :-)

Answer (score 2):

These are simply chained promises (obviously asynchronous code), which means that a given .then block executes when the promise has been resolved, and after that continues on the next block.

So in your example:
When the func promise has been resolved, func1 will be executed.
When func1 has been resolved, func2 will be executed.
When func2 has been resolved, func3 will be executed.

Your second example would lead to a different result, which might be wrong or also correct, depending on your desired behavior.
But if the execution of 1 function depends on the result of the previous, then it is crucial to wait for the result before you can continue.